# Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't boot after installation Lenovo IdeaPad 310

Tags: boot, uefi, lenovo

I removed windows 10 from my laptop and installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS instead. The installation was completed and it asked for reboot. When I rebooted, it asked for removing the bootable medium and press enter, but then I encountered a message that the system can't boot and needed bootable medium. (The image below is the error)
[image]

What I have tried is too boot system with boot-repair that asked me to put bios on UEFI mode and it repaired the boot successfully. But I still can't boot.
I have also tried different bios status but still it doesn't boot.
PS: during installation it asked to create an efi partition or the system won't boot after and I created a 200 mb partition for it.

My system is Lenovo IdeaPad 310 core i7

Update :

This is how I have partitioned my hard disk. ( I've taken this photo after installing ubuntu. That is why it shows Ubuntu installed on sda2. Os is installed but not boot.)

[image]

And this is the output of this command: sudo fdusk -l /Dev/sd[abcd]

[image]

Comment: Could you please describe what you did during install? In what way is the harddisk partitioned, and what type did you use for the EFI partition (just making a 200 Mb FAT32 partition is not enough)? Please update your question with this info and include the output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sd[abcd]`.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I added what you wanted to my question. Hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you for the 'screenshots'. You did most of it right, BUT your harddisk is partitioned in the old-fashioned way: `dos` instead of `gpt`. This means that you cannot boot using UEFI, even though you have correctly made an EFI partition. So, put your BIOS back into Legacy mode to suit your hard disk. The first screenshot suggests you have GRUB installed on `/dev/sda` - yoy should be able to boot into GRUB.

Comment: I know it's confusing, but the /boot partition is **not** where Ubuntu is installed, it's just the place where the stuff for the initial start 'lives'. The actual Ubuntu is on /dev/sda1 - you did that right: it's installed the correct way.